# display the input values even after the results are shown

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an html page, which has two fields `From date` and `To date`. On clicking the submit button I'm able to retrieve the information based on the dates and display it,in the same page but my `From date` and `TO date` fields become empty. So how do I hold the values so that they are retained in their respective fields even after the displaying the information.

HTML:

```
  <ion-content ng-init=onViewloaded()>    
    From:
    <input type="date" ng-model="fromDate">
    To:
    <input type="date" ng-model="toDate">
    <button type="submit" ng-click="Save()">Submit</button><br>
    Data:
    {{receivedData.name}}
    {{receivedData.information}}
   </ion-content>
```

Controller:

```
    $scope.receivedData;

    $scope.onViewloaded=function()
   {
     bulkDateService.getData($scope.RetrievedData);
   }
   $scope.RetrievedData = function(data,error)
  {
    $scope.receivedData=data;
  }
    $scope.save=function()
   {
    var dataToSend={'from':$scope.fromDate, 'to':$scope.toDate};
    bulkDateService.postData(dataToSend,error);
   }
```

So what am I missing to do, in-order to display the `From date` and `To date` in their fields even after loading the data?

Comment: `<button type="button" .../>`

Comment: On clicking Im able to make a submission

Comment: dont submit... Your Submit  refresh the page... Or PreventDefault in the save.

Comment: if I dont use then how to send the data to controller and service

Comment: So no help in this........ :(

Comment: I just tested it, and it's working fine. Can you create a plunkr and share ?

Comment: Can I use cookies for storing the date

Comment: Is the page getting reloaded ?

Comment: yes  its getting reloaded @suzo

Answer (score 0):

Since you are passing the objects by references in `var dataToSend={'from':$scope.fromDate, 'to':$scope.toDate};`, probably they are getting deleted or changed inside theis function `bulkDateService.postData(dataToSend,error);` (when you alter the field 'to' and 'from' of `dataToSend`.

To try this out, send a copy of the dates instead of the reference and see if that fixes your problem. Like this:

```
var dataToSend={'from':angular.copy($scope.fromDate), 'to':angular.copy($scope.toDate)};
```

And try to avoid ng-init directive, keep controller logic away from view whenever you can. For this you can simply call the function on the controller:

```
$scope.onViewloaded=function()
   {
     bulkDateService.getData($scope.RetrievedData);
   }
$scope.onViewloaded();
```

Or even better, use ionic's view events: [Ionic Docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionView/)

```
$scope.$on("$ionicView.beforeEnter", function(event, data){
   $scope.onViewloaded();
});
```

Comment: `angular.copy` performs a deep copy, if I change the dates will it retain the new values ?

Comment: In the view and the controller, yes. Inside the bulkDateService, No it won't, unless you call the save() function again to copy and send the new values. Another option is review your service and never modify the input parameter so the dates don't get erased.